# CSS triangle filling for a progress bar

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I actually googled and searched some info but couldn't find it.

My aim is to achieve something similar to progress bar styling such as filling inside of triangle. Is there any ways? [image: filling]

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaxrillo/bkaxzLnu/1/)

```
.angle {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 75px solid transparent;
    border-right: 75px solid transparent;       
    border-bottom: 75px solid black;
}
```

Comment: will the outside of the triangle be a block colour?

Comment: @jbutler483 sorry.. what do you mean by block colour?

Comment: will your background be a solid colour (i.e. outside your triangle)?

Comment: @jbutler483 it is not important actually. The thing I need something similar to the progress bar or similar to this. Is there any way can I create like progress bar with triangle?

Comment: [Yes, there is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281127/css-arrow-progress-bar). Use this idea would be my advice...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to make the triangle, I would use two pseudo elements to 'cut it out' of the square div. Then, with a nested div, use absolute positioning to allow you to 'fill' it to a certain value (by setting the `.amount` div's height in %).

```css
.amount {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  background: tomato;
}
.tri {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: lightgray;
}
.tri:before,
.tri:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 200px solid white;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 8;
}
.tri:before {
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  left: 50%;
}
.tri:after {
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  left: 0;
}
.tri:hover .amount {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tri">
  <div class="amount"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice but thats pretty much achievable using pseudoelements only with one element

Comment: @TimKrul: Yes, but when manipulating the 'amount', it would be much more sensible to manipulate a 'real' element than the limited pseudo element for that...

Comment: How did I know you would have an answer on this question! Haha, nice work.

Comment: @Ruddy: I have no idea :P

Answer (score 1):

May something like this?

```
.angle {
    position: relative;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
}

.angle:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid black;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkaxzLnu/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another **CSS ONLY**, **NO-BORDERS**, **NO AFTER/BEFORE HACKS** option:

You could use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path). It allows you to show only part of an element and hide the rest.

So you could do something like this:

```css
  .amount {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
    background: tomato;
  }

  .tri {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ddd;

    /* triangle */
    clip-path: polygon( 100% 0%,100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
  .tri:hover .amount {
    width: 100%;
    background: chartreuse ;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tri">
  <div class="amount"></div>
</div>
```