# shape with gradient css3

Tags: html, css, background, css-shapes

I have two shapes triangle with css:

Triangle Top Left

```
#triangle-topleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

Triangle Top Right

```
#triangle-topright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

My question is how can I add background  **gradient** to these **2 triangles**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will struggle with the way you have created the triangle to create a cross browser solution to this.

Instead, one possibility (if you have a solid color background) would be to adapt [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29538717/3436942) into something like:

```css
.amount {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  background: tomato;
}
.tri {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgb(34,34,34); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%, rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(34,34,34,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(237,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222222', endColorstr='#ed0000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
.tri:before,
.tri:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 200px solid white;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 8;
}
.tri:before {
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  left: 50%;
}
.tri:after {
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tri">
</div>
```

---

An alternative method would be to use a pseudo element, which allows you to have a gradient'ed background colour as well if need be:

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  
  
  
  background: rgb(34,34,34); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%, rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(34,34,34,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(237,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222222', endColorstr='#ed0000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

IE 9 Support

```css
.wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.tri {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  
  
  
  background: rgb(34,34,34); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%, rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(34,34,34,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(237,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%,rgba(237,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222222', endColorstr='#ed0000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"><div class="tri"></div></div>
```

Comment: I send a email via your web page

Comment: @user3185638: see very last snippet ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all within one div with just adding an after to the statement.

Example:

```css
.triangle_topleft {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0%;
  clip: rect(auto, 180px, auto, 100px);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.triangle_topleft::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #70879e), color-stop(100%, #3f4c6b));
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.triangle_topright {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  clip: rect(auto, 180px, auto, 100px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.triangle_topright::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #70879e), color-stop(100%, #3f4c6b));
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle_topleft"></div>

<div class="triangle_topright"></div>
```

Comment: I agree, it may be a better option to use this in the future, but right now unfortunately, browser's aren't quite there yet... but +1 for intuition.