# How animate the height of the background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I have tried the following scenario which I need to animate my background image like filling from bottom to top on hover of my div. Whereas my animation is not like filling from bottom instead its like sliding from bottom to top. Can any one suggest me the right way how I can achieve my result. I am ok with jQuery animation as well and css3 keyframe animation.

Below is my code with fiddle

```css
.bg {
  background: url("https://9887c7297bf844d024e4cccb28a722f62dbe3d73.googledrive.com/host/0B6jEeghp1bpxfkszMFVRcDZBdGF4d012d0hjaS0xWTRvRkh6SDNEUFhUb2pETzlSYWZtbzA/work_home.png") no-repeat center;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
span {
  background: url(https://9887c7297bf844d024e4cccb28a722f62dbe3d73.googledrive.com/host/0B6jEeghp1bpxfkszMFVRcDZBdGF4d012d0hjaS0xWTRvRkh6SDNEUFhUb2pETzlSYWZtbzA/work_home_animate.png) no-repeat top 32px center;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.bg:hover span {
  height: 184px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"><span></span>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vbyccww8/)**

Comment: you might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28282532/3436942) useful

Comment: @jbutler483 i tried from top to bottom and thats doing good but when i tried bottom to top thats where Iam facing trouble. :(

Comment: You can use four images like layers

Comment: Four images like can you explain me little bit @MarikselAzemaj

Comment: You can use two images like layers  1- an square layer which will create the till effect: 2- the house layer with transparent borders: note: you must to make the background color same as house border color. the. The square layer must be behind the hose so when it go up it will create the effect of filling borders.

Comment: Or instead of the first image you can use a div

Comment: I would consider this approach (from bottom to top):
Layer 1: Black House
Layer 2: Grey House Outline
Layer 3: Dark Grey House Outline
Layer 4: A white "mask" of the house.

Layer 4 should take on the shape of the house so that if you were to fill the inside of it, you would see the shape of the house.  Then when you animate in Layer 3, it is just a square so it will create that fill effect.

Comment: @Benjamin: Could you possibly explain what you mean by bottom to top please?

Comment: @jbutler483 you could refer the answer of Dolphin_Wood thats what I exactly wanted but being the position is fixed if i scroll down the image stick to the same position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setting `background-position` to be bottom will be helpful:

```css
.bg {
  background: url("https://9887c7297bf844d024e4cccb28a722f62dbe3d73.googledrive.com/host/0B6jEeghp1bpxfkszMFVRcDZBdGF4d012d0hjaS0xWTRvRkh6SDNEUFhUb2pETzlSYWZtbzA/work_home.png") no-repeat center;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  background: url(https://9887c7297bf844d024e4cccb28a722f62dbe3d73.googledrive.com/host/0B6jEeghp1bpxfkszMFVRcDZBdGF4d012d0hjaS0xWTRvRkh6SDNEUFhUb2pETzlSYWZtbzA/work_home_animate.png) no-repeat;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height .5s;

  background-position: center bottom;
}

.bg:hover span {
  height: 152px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"><span></span></div>
```

Comment: Thats was real clever answer but when I scroll because of the fixed position my content is sticked with the same position.

Comment: @Benjamin: Updated. I found that only specify the size of background image could work very well.

Comment: You are a life saver thats really what i wanted i owe you.

Comment: Its not about the `background-image-size` is all about the `background-image-position: center bottom` that make the difference.

Comment: @Benjamin: oh right! Seeming I had scored lucky hit XD

Comment: Yep this is your lucky day.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this. The brown div "slides" from the bottom to the top. I hope this is what you need.

You've to use your [background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) instead of the colors of course.

```js
function onClick(){
  document.getElementById("second").style.height = "0px";
}
```

```css
div{
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#first{
  background-color: brown;
}

#second{
  background-color: beige;
    transition: height 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second" onclick="onClick()"></div>
```

Comment: I tried with your example but it didn't help me can you just update the fiddle link with the images I have.

Comment: @Benjamin sorry but your JSFiddle is a bit confuse. You've done a lot of CSS stuff which is not considered best practice. If you change "background-color" to "background-image" (of course you've to provide the URLs too) in my example you should exactly have what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't an exact replica, you could use pseudo elements to create this, removing the need for an image at all:

```css
.square,
.mini-square {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
}
.square:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 50px solid white;
  border-right: 50px solid white;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 8;
}
.square:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 125px solid white;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 8;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.square:hover span {
  height: 100%;
}
.mini-square {
  height: 140px;
  width: 110px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 70px;
  background: tomato;
}

.mini-square:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -70px;
  left: -20px;
  border: 75px solid transparent;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-color: tomato;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 8;
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <span></span>
  <div class="mini-square">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what i expected but instead using pseudo elements can you please implement with the background images coz i have to use the same scenario for different images with different shape so if this is a common to all I really thank full to you.

Comment: @Benjamin: Your image implementation will always cause issues, mainly because of the way they are generated. This kind of functionality (pseudo elements,etc) can be adapted to different shapes. If not, then SVG would be the answer.

Comment: Yes i do agree with you and thanks for the effort that you made for be.